# Nested resources in Chef InSpec

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, inspec

Is it possible to use one resource inside other resource in Chef InSpec?

**Example:**

```
 describe command('su srijava') do
     describe file ('/app/java/latest') do     
         it{ should exist }
     end
 end
```

It throws an error like:

```
`method_missing': undefined method `file' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::CommandSuSriava:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Actually what I want to do is that I need to run a utility that is installed in other user and I have to check the output returned from that session and verify it. Example :

- I installed java as *srijava* user
- Now in Inspec I wrote the command to test the Java version (Assume that the `java -version` runs only in that user and not as *root*).
- if I use `su srijava`, then I do not get the output returned back to
  the root session and the test fails
- If I run without `su srijava` then my utility will throw an error that
  the user is not *SriJava*

Code with `su` :

```
describe command('su srijava ; cd /app/java; ./java --version') do
        its('stdout') { should match('1.7') }
 end
```

Code without `su`:

```
describe command('cd /app/java; ./java --version') do
        its('stdout') { should match('1.7') }
 end
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Noah pointed out, nested describe blocks are not supported yet. I also think you do not need those.

```
result = command('runcommand').stdout
filename = result + '/path'
describe file (filename) do     
  it{ should exist }
end
```

On the other hand, you could use the `bash` resource to run multiple commands. `command` uses the default shell of the user, `bash` enforces it. This enables you to:

```
describe bash('su srijava ; cd /app/java; ./java --version') do
  its('stdout') { should match('1.7') }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, nor does that make any sense because the two wouldn't be combined even in normal RSpec. If your issue is you need to check a file as root you can use InSpec's sudo options. I'm not sure why you would want to check if a file exists as a certain user, but that isn't supported.

Comment: `su` runs a new shell as the target user. It doesn't magically affect commands later in the same shell. You want something like `sudo -u whatever bash -c "cd /foo; something"`

Comment: This is not working. I did it like                                                        `describe command('sudo -u whatever bash -c "cd /foo; something" ') do
        it { should exist }
 end`                                                                                                             and It is saying like `expected command sudo -u whatever bash -c "cd /foo; something" to exist`

Comment: The `command` resource in InSpec doesn't respond to the `exist` matcher. Commands have matchers for things like stdout/err content and exit status.

Comment: `command` resource does have `exist` matcher. See [this](https://docs.chef.io/inspec_reference.html#id28) for reference.